# Zend form: how to restore proper view after validation failure?

Tags: forms, validation, zend-framework

I have an issue with redisplaying a view after a validation failure with a Zend form.

My initial action looks like

```
public function test1Action() {
    // get a form and pass it to the view
    $this->view->form = $this->getForm(); 

    // extra stuff I need to display 
    $this->view->name = "Bob";
}
```

and the view

```
Hello <?= $this->name?>
<?php echo $this->form;?>
```

The problem comes when the action "test2" called after the form is submitted has a validation error :

```
public function test2Action() {
    if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        return $this->_forward('test1');
    }

    $form = $this->getForm();
    if (!$form->isValid($_POST)) {
        $this->view->form = $form;
        return $this->render('test1'); // go back to test1
    }
}
```

Indeed, the variable "name" is lost and the view is incorrect. Instead of saying "Hello Bob" it says "Hello".

How should I handle that ? should I redirect to test1 instead of just rendering test1 again ? how ?

**EDIT**

Following the answer of Mr Coder, here is what I ended up with :

Controller:

```
    public function getForm() {
        // what is important is that the form goes to action test3 and not test4
        // SNIP form creation with a field username
        return $form;
    }

    public function test3Action()
    {
        $this->view->form = $this->getForm();
        $this->view->name = "Bob";

        if(!$this->getRequest()->isPost())return;

        if($this->view->form->isValid($_POST))
        {
            //save the data and redirect
            $values = $this->view->form->getValues();
            $username = $values["username"];

            $defaultSession = new Zend_Session_Namespace('asdf');
            $defaultSession->username = $username;

            $this->_helper->redirector('test4');
        }
    }


    public function test4Action()
    {
        $defaultSession = new Zend_Session_Namespace('asdf');
        $this->view->username = $defaultSession->username;
    }
```

test3.phtml

```
Hello <?= $this->name?>
<?php echo $this->form;?>
```

test4.phtml

```
success for <?php echo $this->username;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bring your bob back do

```
public function test2Action() {
    if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        return $this->_forward('test1');
    }

    $form = $this->getForm();
    if (!$form->isValid($_POST)) {
        $this->view->form = $form;
        $this->view->name = 'bob';        
        return $this->render('test1'); // go back to test1
    }
}
```

But I will advice my solution of handling form which goes something like

```
public function test2Action()
{

   $this->view->form = new My_Form();

   if(!$this->getRequest()->isPost())return;   

  if($this->view->form->isValid())
   {
    //save the data and redirect 
       $this->_helper->redirector('success');
   }

  }
```

inside your test2.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->form ?>
```

}

This approach save you from creating multiple action for saving one form and changing view manually.

Comment: "To bring your bob back do" : thank you for making me laugh :)
I am not sure to completely understand your way of handling form. Do you get rid of test1 and keep only test2 ?

Comment: Could you check my edit in the question to see whether it is what you had in mind ? thank you

Comment: yes to make it even better (success msg handling) use ZF flashmessenger action helper http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.flashmessenger